# Concatenate cells based another worksheet?

Tags: excel-formula

Would anybody know how to concatenate, if a cell value is equal to a cell in different range and concatenate with another relevant cell based on unique ID; the result tab we should have DAS G45 e.g:

[image]

Thank you,
A

Comment: will there always only be one line, what if DAS appears multiple times?

Comment: If DAS appear multiple times it will have to check the unique ID to concatenate. I forget to put the unique ID.

Comment: please [edit] the post to include all that you need to get the correct output, otherwise what we help you with may not work in real life.

Comment: Hi Scott, I am edit the post to include the unique IDs. thank you

Comment: Do you have Office 365 Excel or an older version?

Comment: Yes i have Office 365 Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN and FILTER:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTER(Sheet2!A:B,(Sheet2!A:A=A2)*(Sheet2!C:C=B2),""))
```

Where

```
Sheet2!A:A = Worksheet 2 column 1
Sheet2!C:C = Worksheet 2 column 3
Sheet2!A:B = Worksheet 2 column 1 & 2
A2 = Worksheet 1 Column 1 first row of data
B2 = Worksheet 1 Column 2 first row of data
```

[image]

Comment: The formula is not validating when I enter it for some reason...

Comment: what do you get as an error?  If it is not a valid formula then check to see if you use `;` instead of `,` as the delimiter.

Comment: I don't have any error msg, the comma are correctly used. could this be because of data filter applied?

Comment: I do not understand, if you get no error then what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe your version of office 365 does not have FILTER yet? (Some companies don't release it)

Comment: It's really strange, because in the formula argument i do have the formula result concatenating the cells. Is there any other way to do this?
The cell is just returning the formula not no result.

Comment: Then you may have the cell set to Text or you may have the system set to show the formulas.  Try changing the cell to General not text format.  or try hitting Ctrl-` @Anton

Comment: @ScottCraner no luck the cells are in General and the Ctrl ' is not returning the result.
Is there an app for Stackoverflow to access? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`=Worksheet1$A1&" "&INDEX('Worksheet 2'!$B:$B,MATCH('Worksheet1!$B1, 'Worksheet 2',$C:$C,0))`
If I understand it correctly.

This is provided that Column 1 & 2 in Worksheet 1 are Column A and B and data starts in the first row and Columns 2 & 3 in Worksheet 2 are column B and C.
Then the formula can be used and copied down anywhere in the file from the first row.